# Pandas reading csv with a escaped quote in a quote

Tags: python, pandas, csv

### Setup

The task is to read this csv with Pandas (i.e.. `pd.read_csv(filename)`):

```
title,description
Jeans,"blue"
Jeans,"2\" seam"
Jeans,"2\" seam, blue"
```

Code to try this

```
import os
import pandas as pd

with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write('''title,description
Jeans,"blue"
Jeans,"2\" seam"
Jeans,"2\" seam, blue"
''')

pd.read_csv("/tmp/test.csv")
```

### Problem

Expected output:

```
    title   description
0   Jeans   blue
1   Jeans   2" seam
2   Jeans   2" seam, blue
```

But in practice it can:

- Read the first line no problem
- Read the second line incorrectly but does not throw an error
- Fail to read the third line with an error

Result from reading up to the *second* line:

```
    title   description
0   Jeans   blue
1   Jeans   2 seam"
```

Error from reading up to the *third* line:

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line
>   3, saw 5

This seem like a common problem. Is there a configuration in Pandas `read_csv` that can handle this?

Comment: What do you expect the answer to be?

Comment: Added expected output to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [the `escapechar` is None](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). To specify the backslash as the one-character string used to escape the delimiter (e.g. the doublequote), use `escapechar='\\'`:

```
In [23]: pd.read_csv('data', escapechar='\\')
Out[23]: 
   title    description
0  Jeans           blue
1  Jeans        2" seam
2  Jeans  2" seam, blue
```

Comment: Strange. That actually doesn't work for me. Can you try it with the code snippet I posted (edited) above? I still get the same error.

Comment: @foobar: Inspect the contents of `/tmp/test.csv`. You'll see that the escaped doublequotes were parsed by Python as plain doublequotes and therefore the string that was written to the file did not contain backslashes. To fix your example code, change the multiline string to a **raw** multiline string: e.g. `r'''title,...'''` instead of `'''title,...'''`.

Comment: Awesome, got it! Thanks!