# Jupyter Notebook - Python / Displays double quotes at the end of string/text on each row

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, quotes

I have pipe delimiter text file which I read it using the pd.read_csv(filepath,sep="|",encoding='utf-8'). However, when displaying the data in dataframe I realized that some text columns contain measurements in inches which by the way are represented with double quotes: |Table 38"x38"| and sometimes there are fields that also contain double quotes and can look like this  |"Table 38"x38""| but the data displayed in dataframe translates quotes and places all the quotes at the end of the text instead of displaying quotes in their correct places. Therefore, the data will look like this: |Table 38x38""|. I would like to know how I can make Jupyter Notebook or DataFrame to display the quotes correctly since they represent measurements.

Please help!

Comment: Can you give some example data so that we can reproduce this? Some more breathing room in your post would also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you outputting using print?  display?

Comment: I using the df.head() to display data or i have used the print method. The most bizarre part is that whenever i saved results to excel data is reflected the same as in the dataframe with incorrect placement of the quotes.

Comment: here is an example of the data: XX|YY|"22161"|"222222"|"Y"|""|"N"|""|"APPLICATOR COTTON TIP 3" STER"|""|"804"|"42141502"|"4606900"|""|"BX"|200|"1"|"Y"|3|"11128"|""|"018-460"|""|""|"CS"|""|3.4500|""|""|""|"N"

Answer (score 0):

The trick based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51289809/8508004) is to use an escape character to designate quotes to respect as symbols. Let's use a backslash as the escape character.
In the `pd.read_csv` you'd specify that with the addition of `escapechar='/'`.
In your CSV file you'd want cases like "Table 38"x38"" to then become "Table 38\"x38\"". However, you don't want to do those changes by hand, and so you'll programmatically go through the file and change any cases of 'internal' quotes to `/"`.

The code below will do that with the data file you designated with `filepath`.

```py
import pandas as pd
intermdt_txt = ""
with open(filepath, 'r') as input:
    for line in input:
        altered_line_parts = []
        parts = line.split("|")
        for part in parts:
            if part.startswith('"') and part.strip().endswith('"'):
                part = '"' + part[1:-1].replace('"','/"') + '"'
            altered_line_parts.append(part)
        intermdt_txt += '|'.join(altered_line_parts) + "\n"        
%store intermdt_txt > intermdt_txt.txt
df = pd.read_csv("intermdt_txt.txt",sep="|",encoding='utf-8', escapechar='/')
```

You may need to adjust the escape character to suit your specific needs.

Comment: Good evening Waye. This is an amazing solution! Thank you very much! In regards to the "You may need to adjust the escape character to suit your specific needs." I encounter some fields which also use the "/" and is now making some columns to either merge or move the text to the next column: Examples: PCS 10.25MM TUBE ADAPT SET"|"|8295750"
PCS MICRO TUBE ADAPT SET"|"|8333130"
TUBE 18" EXT W CONN LTX N"|"|150615"
COMPLY STEAM CHEM INTGRTR W"|"|1243RE"

Comment: for some reason some rows are keeping the pipes and moving the text to the next columns which are not aligned to their respective column. Any suggestion please kindly advise. This may be caused by some text include the "/" as part of the text as separator of a package string such as Box/250/Each kinda' thing

Comment: Thank you all for your support in solving this issue!

Comment: I was originally using an ampersand as the 'escape character' in my testing but worried your data file might use that. If you want to try with that, you'd replace the backslash on line 9 and line 13 of my code with the `@` symbol. (I probably should have defined that as a variable in the code.) Or use any character that isn't in your data file. You can probably find some code that you could use to scan the file for instances. `grep` would be handy for that if you are on a unix based system.

Comment: I suspect for the merging, the issue is that you have some cases where there is a single `"` between the delimiter. It is a little hard to tell because the example you added has many fewer delimiters. (Sometimes when things get long for a comment you can use [a pastebin-like site](https://designmodo.com/share-code-snippets/) to share larger blocks of data or code in a comment here.) If that indeed is the case, a find and replace in a copy of your original CSV file to find the cases of `|"|` and replace them with `|""|` might fix it. You'd then point the code I provided at the modified CSV.